# Loop through each PDF file in directory

Tags: c#, foreach

I need to upload each file to our File management system. I am trying to create a loop to access each PDF file and then perform an upload. I have ended up in a mess. Any hints how to do it right?

Here is my mess:

```
        string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\temp\");

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

        var pdfPath = @"C:\temp\";
        var pdfFiles = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp\\").GetFiles("*.pdf");
        var PdfFilename = pdfFiles[0].Name;

        var destinationFile = pdfPath + PdfFilename;

        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))

         { 
            // Rest of the code goes here 
         }
```

---

**EDIT:**

By this code:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    // Rest of the code goes here 
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

I am getting full path of each file, like `C:\temp\Power EMC Brochure.pdf`. How can get each files name later inside loop? I mean I need to cut a name of each file from full path for example `Power EMC Brochure` as a file name to specify for our file management system.

Is it something like this?

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    // Rest of the code goes here 
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);


    file.Name;
}
```

Comment: `I have ended up in a mess`, we all do. What's the actual issue you are having? From what I can see, there's a lot that can be removed... and you are doing some double back code...

Comment: `var pdfFiles = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp\\").GetFiles("*.pdf")` gets you what you need; it's a `FileInfo` array; every object in that array is a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_) object that has all these [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties) you have access to.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want 2 loops one for the current code, and one for later? All you want is to loop through once and reuse the same code later without getting all the files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    // Rest of the code goes here 
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

[DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://DirectoryInfo.GetFiles) returns a set of FileInfo objects and the FullName of these objects is the full filename complete with path. So you don't need to merge again the source path with the filename to form the string needed to execute your upload.

And if you need more details about your file you just need to look at the properties provided by the [FileInfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) where you can also find the

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);  // Without path     
}
```

Comment: `var pdfFiles = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp\\").GetFiles("*.pdf");` what's wrong with that approach the OP is already doing? Also OP hasn't specified what the actual issue is, maybe we need to wait to find out what the issue is.

Comment: @Steve maybe you can add an example how to get just a name without extension? `file.Name` returns `Power EMC Brochure.pdf`. How to get just `Power EMC Brochure`?

Comment: You can apply [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension) to the file.Name string